# How to draw a simplex tableau in LaTex?

Tags: tables, arrays

I would like to draw a simplex table as follows,

[image: correct]

I tried,

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc|cccccccc|c}
           &     & x_1 & x_2  &  x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3  & a_2  &  a_3  &   \\
 \text{Basis} & c_B &  12 &   18 &   10 &  0  &  0  & 0    &   -M &   -M  & \text{RHS} \\ \hline
 s_1   &  0  & 2   &  3   &   4   &  1    & 0   & 0    &   0  &  0   &  50 \\
 a_2   & -M  & 1   &  -1  &  -1   &  0    & -1  &  0   &   1  &  0   &  0  \\
 a_3   & -M  & 0   & 1    & -1.5  &  0    & 0   &-1    &   0  &  1   &  0  \\ \hline
    &     & -M  & -0   &  2.5M &  0    & M   &  M   &  -M  &  -M  &  0  \\
    &     &12+M & 18   &10-2.5M&  0    & -M  &  0   &   0  &  0   &   \\
 \end{array}
 \end{equation}
```

However I get, with an issue $z_j$, and $c_j-z_j$ are not in the middle of column,
[image: incorrect]

edit: And how I can draw similar of this red markers on the same tableau as follows?:
[image: with markers]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I will suggest to use also `siunitx`.

Comment: Regarding your recent edit: please only ask one question per question.

Comment: @leandriis, OK..

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you. Is siunitx a package in LaTex?

Comment: Yes now I put the link: https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx. It is uses also into the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to center `z_{j}` and `c_{j}-z_{j}` over two columns, use the `\multicolumn` command as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{cc|cccccccc|c}
           &     & x_1 & x_2  &  x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3  & a_2  &  a_3  &   \\
 \text{Basis} & c_B &  12 &   18 &   10 &  0  &  0  & 0    &   -M &   -M  & \text{RHS} \\ \hline
 s_1   &  0  & 2   &  3   &   4   &  1    & 0   & 0    &   0  &  0   &  50 \\
 a_2   & -M  & 1   &  -1  &  -1   &  0    & -1  &  0   &   1  &  0   &  0  \\
 a_3   & -M  & 0   & 1    & -1.5  &  0    & 0   &-1    &   0  &  1   &  0  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{z_{j}}     & -M  & -0   &  2.5M &  0    & M   &  M   &  -M  &  -M  &  0  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c_{j}-z_{j}}    &12+M & 18   &10-2.5M&  0    & -M  &  0   &   0  &  0   &   \\
 \end{array}
 \]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. The command \multicolumn doesnot work with MathJax in blogspot. Is there another method?

Comment: MathJax only uses a latex-like input syntax while it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology to process this input. So, to be honest, I have no idea.

Comment: Html table elements  have `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes, roughly corresponding to `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`. I don't think that this could answer the OP nor the mathjax problem but could help in HTML coding.